# Angular form validation to show login error messages

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

so I want to try to show the 'Invalid username or password' error message whenever on the login page whenever the user get's them wrong.

My auth.service.ts code is :

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
        response => {
            this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(
                (token: string) => this.token = token
            );
        }
    )
    .catch (
        error => console.log(error)

    );
}
```

And it's implemented in my signupcomponent.ts file like :

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private authService: AuthService,) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSignIn(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signinUser(email, password);

  }

}
```

And the signup.component.html is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <h1 class="display-3" style="text-align: center"> Login  </h1>
    <form  (ngSubmit)="onSignIn(f)" #f ="ngForm"  >
      <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <label for="email"> Email </label> <!--for firebase you auth with email and password -->
        <input type="email" name = "email" class="form-control" id="EmailId" ngModel required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"  style="margin-top: 20px">
        <label for="password"> Password </label> <!--for firebase you auth with email and password -->
        <input type="password" name = "password" class="form-control" id="Password" ngModel required>
        <button style="margin-top: 20px" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid"> Sign In </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So ideally, I would like to put a *ngIf directive after the submit button that will catch the errors made by the signIn function in the auth .service.

As of now, I'm just logging it in the console, and there I see the error : "auth/invalid-email" with the message property: "The email address is badly formatted." when an incorrect email is entered (and similarly for the password) . Is there any way to display these (or rather the custom message 'Invalid username or password') messages from the caught errors in my auth.service in an ngIf div element in my singin component's html ?

Comment: search for formGroup it will be helpful in your case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, you have two ways to do it.

First one, you should do the `then` on your component like below:

Your service:

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
   return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)      
}
```

Your componet:

```
onSignIn(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signinUser(email, password)
     .then(response => {
        this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
         .then(
            (token: string) => this.token = token
        );
     })
     .catch (
         error => this.errorMessage = error.message;
    );
}
```

Second way: create Rxjs Subject on your service:

Your Service:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

     private logInErrorSubject = new Subject<string>();

     public getLoginErrors():Subject<string>{
            return this.logInErrorSubject;
     }

     signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
         firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
         response => {
           this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);
           firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
           .then(
              (token: string) => this.token = token
           );
          }
      )
     .catch (
         error => this.logInErrorSubject.next(error.message);

     );
      }
```

Your component:

```
     private errorMessage:string;

     constructor(private signupService:SignupService){
        this.signupService.getLoginErrors().subscribe(error => {
               this.errorMessage = error;
          });
     }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I just checked again and I don't seem to be able to login if I put the .then in the component instead of the service. Is there any way to declare catch error in the service( in the catch block) but then display it in the signIn component's html?

Comment: Check the second way i provided it.

Comment: Yup, the second method works. Thank you so so much once again !!  This was a big help. :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Would someone be able to tell me why this has no upvotes and at 0 right now?  Solution 2 worked perfect for me.  Is this not a good way to do this?